# Remove cell reuse in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have checked alot of the questions that answer this but I believe I have a special case.

*I want to caveat this by saying that I was working on an app with a friend and he went to work for Apple. I was the designer and he was the developer. He was teaching me Objective-C and Swift. I am updating the app he and I worked on and trying something new with it. Probably way over my head but I am learning alot by working on it and doing tutorials @ Udemy and asking questions with other developers I know.*

So I have a cirumstance where the app is using a UICollectionView to display a collection of "items". When you tap a "item" it animates to a detail view of that item and gives you more information. Cell reuse wasn't a problem until I built out a way to swipe between the items at the detail level. (You can tap into an item detail and then swipe between those details.)

Here is the problem: if the cell of the item isn't on screen when a user moves to the detail view and tries to swipe to that item it won't be displayed.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
KNIIssueCollectionViewCell *cell = (KNIIssueCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kItemCellReuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];

KNIRecommendedItem *item = self.issue.items[indexPath.item];
[cell configureWithItem:item];

KNIRecommendedItemDetailViewController *itemDetailVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([KNIRecommendedItemDetailViewController class])];
itemDetailVC.item = item;
itemDetailVC.transitioningDelegate = self;
itemDetailVC.itemImage = cell.image;
[self.pages addObject:itemDetailVC];
return cell;
```

}

I understanding the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier should be removed, but every re-write I have tried resulted in errors.

Comment: What is the code that you have written after removing dequeue

Comment: Cell reuse isn't your problem.  Anytime you think that disabling cell reuse will fix your problem you probably don't understand your problem. A cell is just a view of some data in your model.  Even if the item that you want to display in your detail view isn't currently displayed in the collection view, the item still exists in your data model and that is where you need to get it from.  You don't have a "special case".

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - That kinda clears up some of the thinking I have had about it as well. But you put it more succinctly than I was in my head. Maybe I am tackling the problem at the wrong location...

Comment: @Paulw11 - Question: Should I be using something other than UICollectionView to display this information? Meaning - is this the wrong type of implementation for the behavior I am seeking?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView
*)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KNIIssueCollectionViewCell *cell = //create new cell instance here

    KNIRecommendedItem *item = self.issue.items[indexPath.item];
   [cell configureWithItem:item];

   // ...other part of code... //
   return cell;
}
```